# MySql error 1242: Subquery returns more than one row, but query cannot utilize JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

This is my query and I have two Products sold on the same bill number.
I want to print both of them. How can this be done without using a JOIN clause?

```
select BillNumber, BillDate,
       (select CustomerName from tblCustomer
        where  tblCustomer.CustomerId = tblBillHeader.CustomerId) as CustomerName,
       (Select ProductId from tblBillDetail
        where tblBillHeader.BillNumber = tblBillDetail.BillNumber) as ProductId
from tblBillHeader;
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Try looking up JOINS

Comment: I am not allowed to use JOINS. I got the wanted results using WHERE clause and JOINS. This particular query should be written without using JOIN. (only using subqueries)

Comment: So logically billdetail will have multiple lines for each billheader.  If you really can't use joins, then teh billnumber and bill date need to be the subqueries and the billdetail has to be the main query.  The issue is since multiple products exist on one bill, and the inline select subquery can only return one row, you're only option is to use billdetail as the main outer query and all the other values will have to be a subquery.  Though this limitation makes NO SENSE.

Comment: Are you able to use old style joins `FROM table1, table2, table 3 where table1.id = table2.table1ID and table3.id = table2.table3id`

Comment: "_I want to print both of them._" - does that mean in one row or multiple (i.e. _two_) rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select BillNumber, BillDate, (select CustomerName from tblCustomer where 
tblCustomer.CustomerId = tblBillHeader.CustomerId) as CustomerName,
tblBillDetail.ProductId as ProductId 
from tblBillHeader
join tblBillDetail on tblBillDetail.BillNumber = tblBillHeader.BillNumber
```

Comment: Why not convert  both sub-queries?

Comment: I am not allowed to use JOINS. I got the wanted results using WHERE clause and JOINS. This particular query should be written without using JOIN. (only using subqueries)

Comment: If you can't use JOINs then your only chance will be to use an aggregate funtion like MIN() or MAX() in the subquery e.g. SELECT MIN(ProductId) FROM ...) or you could use the TOP keyword which will then return only the first row e.g. SELECT TOP 1 ProductId FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

Just use join

```
select tblBillHeader.BillNumber,tblBillHeader.BillDate,tblCustomer.CustomerName,tblBillDetail.ProductId from  tblBillHeader
inner join tblCustomer on tblCustomer.CustomerId = tblBillHeader.CustomerId
inner join tblBillDetail on tblBillHeader.BillNumber = tblBillDetail.BillNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

***PERFORMANCE WILL SUCK...***

But if you can't really use joins...I think mySQL allows you to use the alias of a column in a expression later in the select.

If I can assume that

1. Each tblbillheader.customerID has one and only one record related in customer...
2. Each CustomerID will have many entries in tblBillHeader
3. tblBillDetail.BillNumber associates to one and only one record in tblBillHeader
4. tblBillDetail may have many records for one tblBillHeader.BillNumber

Then you have to start with the table with the most records in the one to many chain... in this case tblbillDetail.  and all the other tables have to be subqueries based on it.

```
SELECT (SELECT BillNumber FROM tblBillHeader WHERE tblBillHeader.BillNumber = tblBillDetail.BillNumber) BillNumber
     , (SELECT BillNumber FROM tblBillHeader WHERE tblBillHeader.BillNumber = tblBillDetail.BillNumber) BillDate
     , (SELECT CustomerID FROM tblBillHeader WHERE tblBillHeader.BillNumber = tblBillDetail.BillNumber) CustomerID
     , (SELECT CustomerName FROM tblCustomer WHERE tblCustomer.CustomerId = CustomerId) as CustomerName
     , ProductId 
from tblBillDetail
```

The only one I'm not positive about is the customerName.  since tblBillDetail doesn't have customerID we have to get it from the header; but since we can't use joins the only way to derive it is from the results of a prior inline select query.  I know Oracle, DB2, or SQL Server would support this concept; but I think I've seen it done in mySQL.

but if not we could have a nested subquery to get it to work I think...

```
SELECT (SELECT BillNumber FROM tblBillHeader WHERE tblBillHeader.BillNumber = tblBillDetail.BillNumber) BillNumber
     , (SELECT BillNumber FROM tblBillHeader WHERE tblBillHeader.BillNumber = tblBillDetail.BillNumber) BillDate
     , (SELECT CustomerID FROM tblBillHeader WHERE tblBillHeader.BillNumber = tblBillDetail.BillNumber) CustomerID
     , (SELECT CustomerName FROM tblCustomer WHERE tblCustomer.CustomerId = (SELECT CUSTOMERID from tblbillHeader where tblBillHeader.BillNumber = tblBillDetail.BillNumber)) as CustomerName
     , ProductId 
from tblBillDetail
```

Now maybe you can't use INNER join but the old style joins would be allowed?  if so then

```
SELECT BH.BillNumber
     , BH.BillDate
     , C.CustomerID
     , C.CustomerName
     , BD.ProductId 
FROM  tblBillDetail BD, tblBillHeader BH, tblCustomer C
WHERE BD.BillNumber = BH.BillNumber
  and C.CustomerID = BH.CustomerID
```

But this is a style of join syntax so I don't think it's allowed based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use JOIN, and you need to use the sub-queries for SELECT fields, then one solution might be to limit the results of the sub-queries. Options for limiting include:

- Using [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) like [MAX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max), [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

  ```
  select BillNumber, BillDate, 
  (select GROUP_CONCAT(CustomerName)
          from tblCustomer 
          where tblCustomer.CustomerId = tblBillHeader.CustomerId) as CustomerName, 
  (Select GROUP_CONCAT(ProductId) from tblBillDetail where tblBillHeader.BillNumber = tblBillDetail.BillNumber) as ProductId 
  from tblBillHeader
  ```

  With [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) all values could be combined into a list (e.g. comma-separated) in one row. But if you wanted those in separate records then that doesn't seem very feasible without using a JOIN (either implicit or explicit). Using MIN/MAX would depend on what possible values could be eliminated...
- Using the [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#idm140033675985088) clause:

  ```
  select BillNumber, BillDate, 
  (select CustomerName 
          from tblCustomer 
          where tblCustomer.CustomerId = tblBillHeader.CustomerId 
          LIMIT 1) as CustomerName, 
  (Select ProductId 
          from tblBillDetail 
          where tblBillHeader.BillNumber = tblBillDetail.BillNumber 
          LIMIT 1) as ProductId 
  from tblBillHeader;
  ```

  Though that likely isn't going to help, since it would omit results.

I attempted to make a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c032e9) to demonstrate these options. While I was able to get the schema saved, it appears that the SQL execution service is not working correctly at the moment... I will update this when I find it is working.